# Oscillating Markovprocess Transition Probabilities

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Suppose we have an irreducible positive-recurrent Markov process $\{X(t), t\geq0\}$ with generator $G$. Let $P(t)$ be its transition probability matrix and $\pi$ its stationary distribution. Then we know that $\pi G=0$ and $P'(t)=P(t)G$ and hence $P'(t)\rightarrow 0$. I would like to have a more intuitive argument as to why $P'(t)$ should converge to 0. For example, suppose $\pi_j=\frac{1}{2}$, what is preventing us from having something like
\begin{equation}
p_{ij}(t)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\sin{t^2}}{t}+\frac{1}{2},
\end{equation}
so that $p_{ij}(t)\rightarrow \pi_j$, but $p'_{ij}(t)$ does not converge to 0.

Comment: I agree that your example function $\sin(t^2)/t$ converges to zero, but its derivative does not.  However, the Markov chain relates $P(t)$ and $P'(t)$, so it avoids such things.  Let's fix the initial condition and view $P(t)=(P_1(t), \ldots, P_N(t))$ as the vector of probabilities for each of the $N$ states at a given time $t$. We know $P'(t)^T = P(t)^TG$. So if $P(t)\rightarrow \pi$, then $P'(t)^T\rightarrow \pi^T G$.  So $P'(t)$ converges to the fixed vector $\pi^TG$ and (since $P(t)$ converges, rather than growing linearly) it must be that $\pi^T G=0$.

Comment: Overall, if $P(t)$ converges to a fixed vector, then its derivative must converge to zero (due to the ODE structure $P'(t)^T = P(t)^TG$). So then I think your question reduces to "why does $P(t)$ converge to a fixed vector?"